# File format issues with Perl script

Tags: perl

I am having issues running a Perl script against some text files that we have been getting from Cisco switches. It seems that, depending on the method we use to get the information from the switch, the file has a different format that is either parsed correctly or ignored by the Perl script.

I'm not sure how to show the format on the question

This format is being ignored:

```
Load for five secs: 32%/0%; one minute: 14%; five minutes: 13%
Time source is NTP, 11:32:05.154 BST Tue Mar 27 2018
Fa0/1         1059225247       10607505            308           4511 
Fa0/13         266860396        1052489          79896              6 
Gi0/1       173770642844       20858446      958514311      452445559 
Gi0/2       161741166272       11443033     1056101155      429442472 
Po6         335511809116       32301479     2014615466      881888031 
Fa0/1         1874849888       10258324        1643899        2235298 
Fa0/13        1146650530        1515709        1754689        9028035 
Gi0/1         1152699582       10607505         206750           4483 
Gi0/2          818776784        3355128         206663           4690 
Po6           1971476366       13962633         413413           9173
```

This format works fine

```
Load for five secs: 8%/0%; one minute: 13%; five minutes: 14%
Time source is NTP, .11:00:56.345 GMT Mon Feb 26 2018

Port            InOctets    InUcastPkts    InMcastPkts    InBcastPkts 
Fa0/1        12479523313       18114137          73428              7 
Fa0/2                  0              0              0              0 
Fa0/3                  0              0              0              0 
Fa0/4       133519690294      108839334          51277              0 
Fa0/5                  0              0              0              0 
Fa0/6        53741520430       53710739          51253              0 
Fa0/7        41441297607       48481526          51268              0 
Fa0/8       135436414967      109360255          51179              0 
Fa0/9                  0              0              0              0 
Fa0/10       15777946932       28964665          92027              7 
Fa0/11       18242079587       37105281          92028              8 
Fa0/12           6957880          94578              2             21 
Fa0/13          14966233         195958              2             20 
Fa0/14           6383951          87892              2             23 
Fa0/15          99056361         626574              8             35 
Fa0/16         534303664        1033306              8             36 
Fa0/17          99952212         629958              8             36 
Fa0/18         518959271        1027977              8             36 
Fa0/19      399717840577      296105605       17969848              0 
Fa0/20                 0              0              0              0 
Fa0/21                 0              0              0              0 
Fa0/22         796038075        4653515          14895          24243 
Fa0/23          81876696         212575          92046             13 
Fa0/24                 0              0              0              0 
Gi0/1       712152233997      245342838     1214298205      700443702 
Gi0/2        41503317082        8378680       78384491      326407250
```

This is the script I use; It works perfectly for what I need. I pasted the non-working text into a "working file" and that worked, so it's almost as if the file is not being picked up.

```perl
#!/perl/bin/perl

use warnings;

my @files = <c:/perl64/SOUTH/*>;

foreach $file ( @files ) {

    open(FILE, "$file");

    while ( $line = <FILE> ) {

        print "$file $line" if $line =~ /Fa/n;
        print "$file $line" if $line =~ /Gi/n;
        print "$file $line" if $line =~ /Te/n;
        print "$file $line" if $line =~ /GE/n;
    }

    close FILE; 
}
```

Comment: "by the Perl script" — What Perl script? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks to **indent properly** your code.

Comment: And **need the expected output** as already said in fisrt comment

Comment: I have never used Perl on Windows, but note that you are reading the file line by line -- this means the input record seperator matters. I would guess that the files use different line separators and that's why it isn't working.

Comment: Your script does not really do much. It just reads the file line by line and outputs filenames in front of lines that contain a certain letter combination, and discards the others. There is no difference between the two files that should be relevant besides the line endings. You say you're on Windows, so that would be it. Note that you `/n` pattern modifier is superfluous and that the patterns should probably start with `^`.

Comment: @simbabque: There's no way I can see that the line endings can affect the result of this. The only difference is that Windows-based files read on a Linux platform will have a spurious CR before the terminating LF.

Comment: What do you mean by *"This format is being ignored"*?

Comment: @Borodin what if it tries to terminate on `CRLF` and can't find it?

Comment: Hi,   I have now got to the bottom of this annoying issue..  I am using PLINK from powershell on a windows server to get the files.  when using the CMD prompt on the same machine it's producing files that do not have the issue.   so it seem to be some kind of encoding issue when using powershell.

Comment: @simbabque: Standard PerlIO always terminates on LF by default. (The value of `$/`). The `:crlf` layer is used on Windows to convert CR LF to LF before the data is scanned by `readline`.

Comment: @normbeef: Can you examine a hex dump of the two files? I know that Windows sometimes uses UTF-16 encoding, which would explain the problem, but I am surprised that it differs between `cmd` and `powershell`. I'm not in a position to test at present. Comparing the sizes of the two files would help: if one is about twice the size of the other then it has UTF-16 encoding.

Comment: You say "it's as if the file is not being picked up". Maybe that's the case. Use perl -d for debugging the script to check that, or just print the name of the file that it's being read before opening it. Also, you don't need the [`n` switch, which is used to prevent parentheses from capturing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers). Some other things: you don't need the quotes around `$file`, the four lines in the regular expression can go into just one `/(Fa/Fi/Ge/TE)/` (and in this case, you might use the `n` switcth), and it's better if you add `use strict` at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, by default, Windows PowerShell generates UTF-16LE output, which means that each character occupies two bytes instead of one

Since you are not decoding this, the regexes aren't matching so nothing is printed

Take a look at [*Understanding default encoding and Change the same in PowerShell*](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/03/03/understanding-default-encoding-and-change-the-same-in-powershell/)

It should work better if you change `open(FILE, "$file")` to `open(FILE, '<:encoding(UTF-16)', $file)` for the PowerShell output (the original quotes are superfluous). Note that there is also an initial BOM character which you may need to remove